# Solve Fibonacci Number using dynamic programming but get crazy slow running time

Tags: fibonacci

I am attempting to solve nth Fibonacci number using dynamic programming and here is my code:

```
class Solution:
    def fib(self, n: int) -> int:
        result = [0]*(n+1)
        
        if n==0:
            return 0
        
        elif n==1:
            return 1
        
        else: 
            result[n] = self.fib(n-1) + self.fib(n-2)
            return result[n]
```

I run on leetcode and it took more than 2000 ms to finish.

The solution on leetcode only takes 28 ms to finsih:

```
class Solution:
    cache = {0: 0, 1: 1}

    def fib(self, N: int) -> int:
        if N in self.cache:
            return self.cache[N]
        self.cache[N] = self.fib(N - 1) + self.fib(N - 2)
        return self.cache[N]
```

I compare my solution with leetcode solution and find that they are actually very similar. Leetcode use dictionary for storing, I use list. But the time complexity for getting item and inserting for both dictionary and list are O(1)? So I don't understand why there is a huge difference in runtime

Comment: At what point do you ever look anything up in `result` and save making recursive calls? DP is more than just storing information; you have to actually call upon that information, e.g. `if N in self.cache: return self.cache[N]` and skip re-doing the work, for it to do any good for you.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you so much! I definitely understand my problem now!